# Google-Chrome dropdown and context menu not showing

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04

I've figured out that google-chrome has a strange behaviour with dropdowns on Ubuntu's Google-Chrome.
It not depends on the dropdown, so I bring you a public [example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select). Now click multiple times on the dropdown example (30-50 times) to show/hide the select input and you will see that the dropdown won't be shown again after reproduce the error. Moreover, if you try to show the context menu by right-clicking on the web or on the chrome bar or buttons, it won't be shown.
I've tried disabling the hardware acceleration without success.
I've tried also on Debian and same problem.
I've tried with Firefox and everything is OK.
The hardware tested is Atom Minix and Intel Nucs, on Ubuntu 22.04 and latest chrome stable versions.

To better understanding you can see this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nNURG7uUNaeTDGktJCqHp8pnBezvzBbb/view?usp=sharing)

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What are drops downs?

Comment: A dropdown for me is the 'select' control. Also can be called dropdown, combobox...

Comment: Sorry none of the terms you use here have any meaning to me and I am sure others will not know either.

Comment: Excuse me. I've edited the post to attach a video.

Comment: I tried very hard, but I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: Just updated from ubuntu 22 LTS to 22.10 and having the same issue with Firefox. Just tried with chrome and it works fine. Before this update, I never had this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, but I have found a simple workaround to be to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch focus to another Application Window and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> again to switch focus back to Google Chrome - and Voila!  Drop-down menus and list items all start working again!

It is unfortunately only a temporary fix and you may have to do it often if filling a form etc. on a web page.

Comment: Hmmm, So glad I've found peoples with the same issue than me! Unfortunately I'm already an ALT-TAB workaround addict so nothing new for me (except that I'm not the only one!).
My Ubuntu 22.04 was upgraded from a initial ubuntu 16.04 (then 18.04, then 20.04) and was even switched from one lenovo hardware to a Dell one without reinstallation (worked perfectly). I was suspecting one of these two action to be a reason, did you do something similar?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and came across this answer on Quora:

> The fix is quick and simple. Open Chrome and in the address bar type
> in “http://chrome://flags” and then press enter.
>
> Scroll down to “Enable touch events“,
>
> Using the dropdown next to “Automatic” change it to “Disabled“. Chrome
> will automatically pop up below asking you to “Relaunch” the browser.
> Click on it.
>
> Once Chrome has restarted check and see if things work the way they
> should.
> [Quora reference](https://www.quora.com/What-do-you-do-when-Google-Chrome-cant-click-on-dropdown-menus)

In my case, in Chrome 113.0.5672.92, that flag didn't exist, but I was able to find the similarly-named chrome://flags/#top-chrome-touch-ui flag. Disabling it did the trick for me.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, amazing!!!! ️